# chamging lights while drawing in open gl

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering

I am curioust about one theme: Say that I have complex scene 
and one light, I can draw scene in parts by sending draw commands
sequentuially (for example in 100 steps).

Can I move the light between sequential calls ? For example i 
would draw table vith light0 close to it then move light0 to
wall then draw wall then move light0 to chair then draw chair.
It would be then somewhat like assembly of it all It is legal
ot it will not work and each whole frame should have one light in
one position? (Same question would also be for other attributes )
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of corse you can. Light position is just a variable that you pass to object shader like this:

```
uniform vec4 fvAmbient;
uniform vec4 fvSpecular;
uniform vec4 fvDiffuse;
uniform float fSpecularPower;

uniform sampler2D baseMap;

varying vec2 Texcoord;
varying vec3 ViewDirection;
varying vec3 LightDirection; <------  here is your light position
varying vec3 Normal;

void main( void )
{
   vec3  fvLightDirection = normalize( LightDirection );
   vec3  fvNormal         = normalize( Normal );
   float fNDotL           = dot( fvNormal, fvLightDirection ); 

   vec3  fvReflection     = normalize( ( ( 2.0 * fvNormal ) * fNDotL ) - fvLightDirection ); 
   vec3  fvViewDirection  = normalize( ViewDirection );
   float fRDotV           = max( 0.0, dot( fvReflection, fvViewDirection ) );

   vec4  fvBaseColor      = texture2D( baseMap, Texcoord );

   vec4  fvTotalAmbient   = fvAmbient * fvBaseColor; 
   vec4  fvTotalDiffuse   = fvDiffuse * fNDotL * fvBaseColor; 
   vec4  fvTotalSpecular  = fvSpecular * ( pow( fRDotV, fSpecularPower ) );

   gl_FragColor = ( fvTotalAmbient + fvTotalDiffuse + fvTotalSpecular );

}
```

Its a shader with texture and one infinitely distant poin light.

If you need to move a light source between objects render its easy like changing variable value.

Comment: He probably uses fixed function light, cause he's talking about `LIGHT0`. And hungarian notation used in this manner really only serves to obfuscate programs. Your shader also lacks the `#version` line.

Comment: Yas you might be right.  But FFP kinda obsolete and long forgotten so im not so shure. But if he is a student then it could be a case.

Comment: it's not forgotten at all. Most introductions to OpenGL on the internet, and almost all (printed) books are written for immediate mode FFP OpenGL. It's certainly not useful anymore, but it's much easier to find than a decent introduction to OpenGL (and modern graphics programming in general, though the situation is a bit better on the DX side).

Comment: It is very helpful answer at all, but really I was thinking about fixed pipe and meant other thing: You render one frame of the image and uses just one (point) light - you change the postion of this light between separate cals so it look somewhat like it would be more than just one light, I am asking if it would be working, or maybe the previous light positions would be cancelled and only last one did matter when all frame would be sent

Comment: It's hard to recall  FFP specifics but after you rendered something and before you cleared color-buffer(screen) result will not gone anywhere except if something is drawn on top of it. So it shuld work, i guess. i did some FFP on delphy many years ago and Opengl FFP has manual z-buffer and color-buffer cleaning in user-created loop.

Comment: And you can use [Blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) if it's supported to render multiply lights on single object as separate pass (add each light render phase results instead of override). So you will have as many light as you want.